# Assets 2.3.2 / Wygwam 3.3

Tags: assets, wygwam

I’m getting an error when saving an entry. I do the following.

- edit entry
- select image in Wygwam (browse server opens Assets)
- save entry

When I save the entry I’ll see an example of the content with a wrong reference to the image.

For example:

http://www.nederlandsedansdagen.nl/uploads/images/Act_Your_Age/Act_Your_Age_Nederlandse_Dansdagen_datum_klein.jpg}" style="height:480px; width:480px”>

Do you have any idea what’s wrong?

I use the latest version of Assets and the latest version of Wygwam.

Hope to hear from you.

Kind regards,

Jasper

Answer (score 1):

The line of HTML you show has a } character at the end of the file name. Do you have an extra closing } in your template code?